# Does ArcGIS Online allow Select By Location?

Tags: arcgis-online, select-by-location

This question refers to the standard ArcGIS Online map, eg http://your-site.maps.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html

Is it possible to perform a Select By Location, eg to find points from one layer which fall within a polygon layer?

There are a bunch of operations available under the Analysis menu but I can't see Select By Location. Is it necessary to build something custom (eg using the ArcGIS JS API, Web AppBuilder, etc) in order to get the Select By Location functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Under the Analysis menu select 'Find Locations' and then 'Find Existing Locations'. Select the layer you want to run your analysis over and click 'Add Expression'. The drop-down on the right hand side of the popup window should show some spatial selection options.

[image]

Comment: Note that this doesn't strictly perform a Select By Location operation - instead it creates a _new_ layer which contains the result of the selection set. I guess to emulate Select By Location exactly, you'd need to write the functionality using one of the APIs